# .htaccess redirect any chars before string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, match

I have an URL like this:

```
/anycharsinsidehere/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html
```

and I want to redirect it to a static page like this:

```
Redirect 301 /*/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html http://www.site.com/new-page-redirected.html
```

How can I obtain this?

I need to match, for example:

```
/dh48hsi3t8y/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html
/fnf;d3thgB/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html
/fkhg84HFB/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html
/nefjb398tFfeihg/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use regex support you need to use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]+/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect\.html$ http://www.site.com/new-page-redirected.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_alias, you want `RedirectMatch` instead of just `Redirect`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html http://www.site.com/new-page-redirected.html
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/hello-this-is-a-page-to-redirect.html http://www.site.com/new-page-redirected.html [L,R=301]
```